# How to integrate API into my WordPress project?

Tags: wordpress

I need your help. Tell me how to use this API Platform [https://api-platform.com/] with WordPress. I need to create a plugin and then my plugin interacts with this API. How does this API integrate into my WP project?

Comment: It depends on the API you need to interact with.
You may take a look at WordPress functions that may help you : wp_remote_get(), wp_remote_post()

Comment: Please share you own research results, first.